# Latest opened program window overrides current software window

Tags: 14.04, xorg, focus

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm finding it very annoying that whenever a program opens its window overrides the current one and gets focus.

For example, I click on the icon of a program that takes some time to launch & in the meantime I am reading something in a browser, but whenever the program starts its window pops up over the current browser window.

Is there any solution available for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think at last I got a solution. Here is the solution:

- get compizconfig-settings-manager
- open compizconfig-settings-manager
- select the category "General"
- click on "General Options"
- select the "Focus and Raise Behaviour" tab
- set "Focus Prevention" level to 'Very High'

That fixed things up for me. Hope it does for you as well.